# Can't put an Image above a ListView using DrawerLayout

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

I wanted to make my app using constraint layout but my side navigation menu just work with DrawerLayout, so now I can't put the elements where I want to.

Even though the image is set as "wrap_content", it is fullscreen and in front of my list, I want it to be above the list.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvLista"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/titleDates"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="#B5D5B5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/titleDates" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/titleDates"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/dias_de_coleta" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to put the ListView and ImageView inside a ViewGroup of it's own because DrawerLayout doesn't support any view positioning constraints. You can treat it as a FrameLayout.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/titleDates"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf=parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/dias_de_coleta" />
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvLista"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/titleDates"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="#B5D5B5" />       

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Additionally:
**layout_alignParentTop** and **layout_below** only works if the container is a RelativeLayout.

And **layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf** only works if the container is a ConstraintLayout.

Using them serves no purpose if your view isn't a child of those viewgroups.

Comment: That worked, thanks! 
Didn't know that I could use different layouts in the same xml, in those lines of code I was desperately trying to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
      <ImageView/>
      <ListView/>
 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: questionnaire want to put list view below the imageview
so in constraint layout put first imageview and below that imageview put the listview and problem solved.